# Merge sorting an array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

hi i have an array of 9 elements

10 , 5 , 2 , 4 , 6 , 1 , 3 , 2 , 6

i have to sort this using merge sort algorithm . My question is that 6 is been used twice so how will it affect the sorting.

Comment: That does depend entirely on your implementation. In a properly implemented merge sort, it should sort without any problems.

Comment: it will either go to the left or right of the other 6 depending on the implementation. Luckily, the net result will be a subarray of `6,6`

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please look at [ask]
and how to create a [mcve]. This will help to get useful answers. stackoverflow.com is not a free coding service.

Answer (score 0):

To understand how this would be sorted lets have a look at how the merge sort algorithm really works.

```
split each element into partitions of size 1
recursively merge adjancent partitions
  for i = leftPartStartIndex to rightPartLastIndex inclusive
    if leftPartHeadValue <= rightPartHeadValue
      copy leftPartHeadValue
    else: copy rightPartHeadValue
copy elements back to original array
```

So lets take the given array `[10 , 5 , 2 , 4 , 6 , 1 , 3 , 2 , 6]` Here's how the algorithm really runs

Initially split the array into partitions of size 1. So each value in the array is individual partition.
Now merge 10 in position 0 and 5 in position 1 together into 1 partition.
Since 10 > 5, Copy the 5 into a new temporary array of size 2, now the right partition is empty and hence copy 10 into it, so you now have a temporary array which is `[5,10]` Then copy it back into the original array in the positions making it

`[5,10,2,4,6,1,3,2,6]`
Now merge the partitions `[5,10]` to  `[2]` in the 2nd index. Since 5 > 2, copy 2 to the temporary array. Since the right partition is empty copy 5 to the temporary array to the right and similar with 10 thus making `[2,5,10]`. Now copy the items back to the original array.
`[2,5,10,4,6,1,3,2,6]`

Now merge the partitions `[4,6]` and since 4 < 6, copy 4 to the left partition and 6 to the right partition of a temporary array and copy them back to the original array. In this case, the array is unchanged and still looks the same.
`[2,5,10,4,6,1,3,2,6]`.

Now merge partitions `[2,5,10]` to `[4,6]`, Since 2 < 4, copy 2 to the temporary array, then since 4 < 5, copy 4 to the array, then since 5 < 6 copy 5 and so on until we have a new partition temporary array `[2,4,5,6,10]` and then copy the elements to the original array `[2,4,5,6,10,1,3,2,6]`

Now merge the items `[1,3]` and similarly with `[2,6]` since value on left side of the partition is lower than that on the right. Then merge `[1,3]` to `[2,6]`. Since 1 < 2, copy 1 to temporary array and then 2 and so on to get the new partition `[1,2,3,6]` and copy it back to the original array making it `[2,4,5,6,10,1,2,3,6]`.

Finally we have 2 partitions to merge i.e. `[2,4,5,6,10]` and `[1,2,3,6]`. Repeat the similar process, since 1 < 2, copy 1 to the temporary array and then 2 (because 2 in left partition <= 2 in right partition) so the value 2 from the left partition gets copied to the temporary array. Then 4 is compared to 2 and the value 2 from the right partition is copied to the new temporary array. Then 4 > 3, so 3 is copied and then the 4 < 6 makes 4 be copied and then 5 < 6 (right partition) makes 5 be copied to the temporary array. When we encounter 6 (left partition) to 6 (right partition) and following the condition `6 <= 6` the value 6 from the left partition gets copied to the temporary array. Then the 6 in the right partition is compared to 10 and 6 < 10 so, 6 gets copied to temporary array and then 10. Then the entire temporary array is copied to the original array thus making us obtain the final array. `[1,2,2,3,4,5,6,6,10]`